# Retrieving a portion from a numpy array, except for some indexes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am having this very annoying problem that I *know* there is a nice solution to, but can't figure out:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10)
i_want_these_idxs = np.array([5,6,7,8,9])
except_for_these = np.array([7,8])
arr = a[???]
# arr should be np.array([5,6,8,9])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `np.setdiff1d(i_want_these_idxs, except_for_these)`?

Comment: @Divakar Oh very nice, that should do it :)

Comment: @Divakar feel free to submit as an answer